# How to find the size of data saved in a HTML5 WebSQL databse?

Tags: html, sqlite, constraints, web-sql, dml

My WebSQL contains images in plain text format(dataURIs). 
I'm capturing photo data and saving it in an HTML5 WebSQL databse. How I can find the size of data saved?

When I use a SELECT query to retrieve this I'm getting a too large resultset error: 'TOO_LARGE_ERR'.

Can anybody help me to find this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [length](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) function with the [LIMIT](http://www.sqlite.org/images/syntax/select-stmt.gif) clause:

```
SELECT length(datauris) FROM foo LIMIT 1,1
```

**References**

- [HTML5 Offline Quota Research](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this doesn't work for me. I wants to know the size of this websql database in MB. Can you help me to get any solution for holding large data in websql? I already have the data in the db. But after a particular limit it is showing error. We are working with Android devices.

Comment: Use one of [several functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364577/how-to-get-the-current-sqlite-database-size-or-package-size-in-android) to get the current size. There is a [5mb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260951/web-sql-storage-limitations-in-chrome-and-android) limit by default, but you can increase it for [websites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784777/increasing-5mb-storage-limit-in-chrome). Refer to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039735/html5-web-sql-db-maximum-table-size) for more help.

Comment: But this I want to do with Mobile device which support android or iOS. there only i'm getting the mentioned error. Please help.